# How to Resolve Interdependency Between Apollo's Mutation and Formik Render Props?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, formik

I'm sure this is a common problem with a well documented solution, but I cannot seem to find the pattern I'm looking for. Here's the situation...

```
<Mutation variables={formValues}>
  {(login, { error, loading }) => (
    <Formik onSubmit={login}>
      {({ values: formValues, handleSubmit ) =>
        <Form method="post">
          // form inputs go here
          <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Login
          </button>
        </Form>
      }
    </Formik>
  )}
</Mutation>
```

Looking at the above code, you can see I have nested render props. But the output of the inner render prop `formValues` is the input to the outer render prop `variables={formValues}`. However, this value is obviously not available to the outer render prop.

### Questions

1. What pattern(s) exist to resolve this dependency issue?
2. Bonus if you can tell me how to do this using something like [react-adopt](https://github.com/pedronauck/react-adopt)

Comment: FWIW the docs show how to transform components that have multiple arguments in the render signature, like the `Mutation` component: https://github.com/pedronauck/react-adopt#leading-with-multiple-params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already pointed out, `variables` can be passed directly to the `mutate` function instead of passing them to the `Mutation` component. With regards to `react-adopt`, according to the docs:

> [Y]ou can pass a function instead of a jsx element to your mapper. This function will receive a render prop that will be responsible for your render, the props passed on Composed component, and the previous values from each mapper.

So I expect something like this should work:

```
const Composed = adopt({
  mutation: ({ render }) => (
    <Mutation mutation={LOGIN_MUTATION}>
      {(login, { loading, data, error }) => render({ login, loading, data, error })}
    </Mutation>
  ),
  formik: ({ mutation: { login }, render }) => ( // **EDIT**
    <Formik onSubmit={values => login({ variables: values })}>
      {render}
    </Formik>
  )
})

const App = () => (
  <Composed>
    {({ mutation: { login, data, loading, error }, formik: { values, handleSubmit } }) => (
      // ...
    )}
  </Composed>
)
```

Comment: I'm trying this, but it doesn't seem to work. I might be missing something. How does Formik's onSubmit get a reference to login when that's defined in Mutation?

Comment: I'm also not clear where you get the `mutation` part of  `{ mutation, render }`, not that it's being used as far as I can see. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Oops, that should be `mutation.logic`, not `login`. Edited the answer with some additional info and fixed the example

Answer (score 0):

## Answers only Question #1 (may be better solutions)

I found a working solution, though there may be others (better?). I still haven't figured out how to compose the render props in this case. But here's my current solution...

```
<Mutation>
  {(login, { error, loading }) => (
    <Formik onSubmit={values => login({ variables: values })}>
      {({ values: formValues, handleSubmit ) =>
        <Form method="post">
          // form inputs go here
          <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Login
          </button>
        </Form>
      }
    </Formik>
  )}
</Mutation>
```

### Notable Changes

1. I changed `<Mutation variables={formValues}>` to `<Mutation>`
2. I changed `onSubmit={login}` to `onSubmit={values => login({ variables: values })}`

Comment: Dang, beat me to it. But I would say passing the variables to the `mutate` call directly is the way to go in this scenario.